# Is there anyway to get parent on self table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657119/how-to-display-parent-id-for-itself-and-children-with-t-sql-recursive-query) in mysql database.

In my case I need to get from:

```
ID | FIRST_REFERENCE  | description
1  | -1               | root
2  | 1                | other_child
3  | -1               | root
4  | 2                | child
5  | 1                | other_child
6  | 3                | child
```

I need to return root with childID, or child if childID refer to a root:

I tried this:

```
SELECT parent.ID 
FROM mytable as child
JOIN mytable as parent
ON child.FIRST_REFERENCE = parent.ID 
WHERE parent.FIRST_REFERENCE = '-1' AND child.ID = '6'
```

But it doesn't work

And then I tried a solution with select case:

```
  SELECT
   CASE FIRST_REFERENCE
   WHEN '-1' THEN ID
   ELSE SELECT rec.ID 
       FROM mytable as rec 
       WHERE rec.ID = main.FIRST_REFERENCE
   END as 'root'
  FROM mytable as main
  WHERE childID = '6'
```

But I get a syntax error.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which version of Mysql?

Comment: MySQL unfortunately does not support recursive queries like SQL server does.

Comment: You can see: http://guilhembichot.blogspot.it/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else will have my problem I solved with a simle LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN parent.ID is NULL THEN child.ID
        ELSE parent.ID
        END AS ID
FROM my table AS child 
LEFT JOIN my table AS parent ON 
  ((parent.ID = child.FIRST_REFERENCE AND parent.FIRST_REFERENCE =  '-1') OR 
  (child.FIRST_REFERENCE = '-1' AND parent.ID = NULL)) 
WHERE child.ID =  '6'
```

Comment: What result do you want for CHILD.ID = 4?